# Why VMs gets destroyed when updating Azure NSG in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

VMs are all up and operation, i just need to update/extend Azure NSG rules to add more sequences. This NGS rules are applied/attached in VM interfaces, and is done during the initial environment VM bringup.

If I do "terraform apply --var-file=module_directory.tfvars --var-file=updated_nsg_rules.tfvars". VMs are destroyed and recreated. Any idea/advise to avoid this? I just need to update NSG rulles.

Below is the module to associate NSG to Interfaces

```
module "vsmart_virtual_interface_NSG_association" {
    source                         = "/Users/reuel/Documents/Terraform/dev_projects/azure_dev/terraform_libs/nsg_assoc"
    location                       = module.Resource_Group.resource_group_location
    virtual_network_interface_ids  = module.vsmart_virtual_interfaces.virtual_network_interface_ids
    network_security_group_rule    = module.Network_Security_Group.network_security_group_rule

    depends_on = [ module.vsmart_virtual_interfaces ]
}
```

NSG resource definition

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "network_security_group_rule" {
  name = "${var.base_name}_${var.site_name}_nsg" location = var.location resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.nsg_rules
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value["name"]
      priority                   = security_rule.value["priority"]
      direction                  = security_rule.value["direction"]
      access                     = security_rule.value["access"]
      protocol                   = security_rule.value["protocol"]
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value["source_port_range"]
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value["source_address_prefix"]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
      description                = security_rule.value["description"]
  }
}
```

Just adding sequence in NSG rules, which is created separately from the VM.

```
- storage_image_reference { # forces replacement
  - id = "/subscriptions/<ID>/resourceGroups/SDWAN-PODS/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/SDWAN/images/vmanage-20-6-5/versions/20.6.5" -> null }
+ storage_image_reference { # forces replacement
  + id = (known after apply)
  + version = (known after apply)
}
```

Comment: The output should say which change is forcing the replacement instead of update.

Comment: is your network interface type is dynamic  or static ?

Comment: no, not dynamic. but do use for_each loop and variables to dynamically create interfaces